# Is display: block and display:inline equivalent to display: inline-block?

Tags: css

I have an div I am viewing in Firebug:

One section has:

```
display: block;
```

Elsewhere, there is:

```
display: inline !important;
```

I would have thought that the `inline` would have overriden the `block`, but neither attribute is crossed out by Firebug.

I have a text input inside the div that can't be clicked in Firefox (works in Chrome). If I cross out either display value, then it works. So it seems both are applied.

So is `display: block` and `display: inline` combined into `display:inline-block`?

Comment: You are correct, display: inline-block; joins the inline behavior with the css box model from display: block;.

Comment: Interestingly, I have a `display: block` elsewhere on the same element that is crossed out. So maybe there is a bug with Firebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, adding `display: block;` followed by `display: inline;` should not be equivalent to `display: inline-block;`. As you suggested, `display: inline !important;` should take precedence over `display: block;`. Is it possible that the `inline-block` value is being attributed to it elsewhere somehow? Perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: "Is it possible that the inline-block value is being attributed to it elsewhere somehow?" - What does that mean?

Comment: @Casebash - Like, in some other style you have `display:inline-block;` or perhaps in the default style for the element.